# How to make a .html file accessible through HTTP but only through a redirect?

Tags: html, asp.net, security, networking

We have a file on our server that's accessible directly through the URL, but it's a security issue at this point.

Our system opens the file in a pop-up window, but you can also get directly to the page by navigating directly to its URL.

How can we prevent this and only allow access to the file through a redirect?

Comment: _"only allow access to the file through a redirect?"_ - that is impossible. You can do something with the referrer, but that is user-supplied and easily faked. Use authentication using credentials or a temporary access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a Session variable on the page that opens the popup:

```
Session["MainPageVisited"] = true;
```

And on the popup page check this value:

```
if (Session["MainPageVisited"] == null || !Session["MainPageVisited"]) 
{
  Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/", true);
}
```

For this solution to work your `html` file will need to be served as an `aspx`. Alternatively, you could create a HTTP Module if you need it to be an actual `html`:

### Create Module

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HelloWorldModule()
    {
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".html"))
        {
            if (Session["MainPageVisited"] == null || !Session["MainPageVisited"]) 
            {
              // Handle it
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

### To register the module for IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 running in Classic mode

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
     </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

### To register the module for IIS 7.0 running in Integrated mode

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note, this was created without testing but it should put you on the right track. Make sure that all requests are mapped through ASP.NET for this to work (Integrated mode or set wildcard application mappings).

Comment: I'm getting an error: `The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context.` What gives?

Comment: Grab it from the context object.

Comment: Alright, I got it working, but it still allows me to open HTML files directly through the URL, even when I'm logged out. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Clear cookies then try

Comment: Not when accessing the file directly through the URL, only when accessing it through the site that launches it.